# Unable to access MS SQL running in one Docker container from an other Docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, docker

I'm running [MS SQL in Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/)

I can access MS SQL from my workstation, but it does not work if I try to connect from my rails docker container:

```
$ docker exec -it 73  bundle exec rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.3)
[1] pry(main)> User.last
TinyTds::Error: Cannot open server 'mssql' requested by the login.
Client with IP address '109.74.176.74' is not allowed to access the server.  
To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run 
sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/tiny_tds-2.0.0/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:53:in `connect'

Cannot open server 'mssql' requested by the login. 
Client with IP address '$MY_EXTERNAL_IP' is not allowed to access the server. 
To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or 
run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to 
create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range. 
It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  mssql:
    image: 'microsoft/mssql-server-linux:ctp2-1'
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=Top-5ecret
      - PATH=$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:/opt/mssql/bin
    ports:
      - '1433:1433'

  website:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec puma --config config/puma/development.rb

    environment:
      - RACK_ENV=development
      - RAILS_ENV=development      
      - DATABASE_URL=sqlserver://sa:Top-5ecret@mssql:1433/sst-staging

      - AAD_SCOPE=openid
      - AAD_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:3000/sst/auth/exchange
      - LOGIN_URI=http://localhost:3000/sst/login

      # Remember to export the following vars to your shell. E.g ~/.profile
      # This will add them to the container if they are present.
      - AAD_TENANT
      - AAD_CLIENT_ID



    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/numbers'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Comment: I am not sure that it is the case, do you run both of them under the same network? "--net networkNameId --ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, it's likely your Azure database has a firewall rule blocking the IP address [allocated to the container](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-a-docker-container-ip-address-explained-with-examples/), which will be different than your machine.

Find your database resource in Azure and look for a blade titled "[Firewall and virtual networks.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal)"  See if there is an ip whitelist, and if your machine's ip is there.  Try to add a whitelist that will match the ip's getting assigned to your container.

As Dmitrij hinted, you could also try different values of the --network parameter to the [docker run command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/).